# Need to delete complete blank rows and columns by python script from xlsx file which is having multiple sheets

Tags: python, xlsx

I have tried many different methods to delete complete blank rows and columns from multiple sheets in xlsx file but no luck.

Example- like i have a xlsx file which is having 40 sheets in it and every sheets contains some entire blank rows and columns and  we need to delete those from each sheets.

Answer (score 0):

u may try use pandas to do that. There is a method called dropna and can work on columns and rows. If the value of "how=all" only the columns/rows there are all empty will be droped.

[pandas.DataFrame.dropna method description](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html?highlight=dropna)